# How to assign values of from a input file to many new (n) variables?

Tags: c++

How to read an "input.txt" file, assigning the value to a new variable?

My input.txt file looks like this:

```
A,0.85,0.72,0.94,.......... n (values);
E,0.11,0.17,0.03,.......... n (values);
L,0.85,0.73,0.31,.......... n (values);
```

I want to create variables for each value of "A". For example:

```
A[0] = 0.85;
A[1] = 0.72;
......
A[n] = certain value from the txt file
```

The same goes for "E" and "L".

Because later I want to perform a for loop from

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){certain equation depending on the value of A, E and L}
```

Comment: There are many existing questions here about reading text files and doing things using C++. Please do a thorough search of this site first before posting a new question, as chances are quite good that the question has been asked and answered here before. Also, you'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how to properly ask a question here.

Comment: Sounds like it's time to read up on [vectors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Dear Chris. Thank you very much. I cheeked already and the things now seem easier. Thanks for the link was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you can create an array like this

```
double * A = new double[n] ;
double * B = new double[n] ;
double * C = new double[n] ;
...
A[0] = 0.85;
A[1] = 0.72;
......
//A[n] = certain value from the txt file
...
delete [] A;
delete [] B;
delete [] C;
```

also you can use vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    int NumberOfElements = 15;
    vector<double> A(NumberOfElements), B(NumberOfElements), C(NumberOfElements);
    A[0] = 0.85;
    A[1] = 0.72;
    A[2] = 0.85;
    A[3] = 0.72;
    A[4] = 0.85;
    A[5] = 0.72;
    //........
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tanks for the idea, now using vector everything seems easier. Thank you very much.